# Cant read file in android

Tags: android, filepath, readfile

I am using this code in my project. I need to read .xls which i have placed in my raw folder. 
    ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();

```
    test.setInputFile(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(("/SPPDashProject/res/raw/aging_busket_key.xls"))).toString());
    try {
        test.read();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
```

### }

```
public class ReadExcel {

    private String inputFile;

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException  {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines

            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    CellType type = cell.getType();
                    if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
                        System.out.println("I got a label: "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                    if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        System.out.println("I got a number "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

what path should i give as my main read class takes path in string format.Plz suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage.myapp" + R.raw.MyXLS);
    String filePath=uri.getPath();
```

Comment: com.mypackage.myapp is the package name defined in menifest or some thing addition i need to add

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code to open file in the /res/raw
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfilename)
You can put your file in the assets folder and use AssetManager to acess it.